# Storing a Response From a Google JavaScript API Request

Tags: javascript, callback, google-plus

While trying out Google's Javascript API with Google+, I ran across a snag.

```
var response;
var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/plus/v1/people/' + "THEUSERID", 
    'params': {}});
request.execute(function(resp){});
```

The execute function (gapi.client.HttpRequest.execute) takes a single argument; a callback function.  However, I do not wish to handle the data immediately after I receive it, I want to store it in the `response` variable I declared at the start of the code.  Is there a way to use the callback argument to store the response?

Forgive me if this has an obvious solution, I'm a little new to JavaScript.

EDIT:
It has been suggested that the callback function be as follows:

```
request.execute(function(resp){response = resp;});
```

However, something curious happens with the function.  Here is the code I used to test:

```
var response;
var request = gapi.client.request({
    'path': '/plus/v1/people/' + userID,
    'params': {}});
request.execute(function(resp){
    console.log("RESP:");
    console.log(resp);
    response = resp;});
console.log("RESPONSE:");
console.log(response);
```

What the console outputs is as follows:

```
RESPONSE:
undefined
GET https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/104815258973759324455?key=XXXXXXX
RESP:
({theactualjsondatathatIreceivedfromthecall})
```

Apparently, the code continues executing /before/ the execute callback function can be called.  I need a way to check for this, so that the code after the execute function is not called until the callback function is run.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
request.execute(function(resp){
  response = resp;
  afterExecute();
});
function afterExecute() {
  // this will not fire until after the response has been set.
}
```

Comment: This should do it.  OP, keep in mind that your `response` var has a scope of the function it is in (if its in one).  So if you need to use it outside of that, be sure to move the declaration.

Comment: That should work, yes, but it appears the execute() function handles the callback a bit different than I thought; I edited the main question to reflect the problem.

Comment: The callback is most likely asynchronous.

Comment: Great; what can I do in order to make the code wait until all the data has been transferred?

Comment: Put the code after `execute` in a function and call that at the end of the `execute` callback. I updated my answer as an example.